# MySQL Slow Performance Related to ci_sessions Table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I built a web app in Codeigniter that's been running fine for about a year, and suddenly the application has become extremely slow at certain times throughout the day. (sometimes 30+ seconds for page loads). I started logging and it turns out some queries are running extremely slow:

```
9.6776      SELECT * FROM (`ci_sessions`) WHERE `session_id` = 'f2f356fb32a4e65ad3eb18f5baa74cfb' AND `user_agent` = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:11' 
28.9770     UPDATE `ci_sessions` SET `last_activity` = '1335753561', `user_data` = 'a:7:{s:6:\"userID\";s:1:\"3\";s:12:\"userFullName\";s:15:\"Christian Varga\";s:5:\"admin\";s:1:\"1\";s:7:\"timeout\";s:5:\"86400\";s:12:\"lastActivity\";s:10:\"1335928202\";s:8:\"prev_url\";s:58:\"http://exampleurl.com\";s:8:\"loggedIn\";s:1:\"1\";}' WHERE `session_id` = 'f2f356fb32a4e65ad3eb18f5baa74cfb'
```

My thoughts are that there's a problem with the database server, because sometimes these exact same queries work fine, then other times throughout the day they are ridiculously slow (as above). But I'm quick to point the finger, so I just wanted to check here to see if anyone thinks it *could* be something wrong with the code, or if it looks like a server issue.

I'd appreciate any thoughts on this.

EDIT: Result of explain select:

```
id  select_type   table         type    possible_keys       key         key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE        ci_sessions   const   PRIMARY,user_agent  PRIMARY     122         const   1
```

Comment: Just for fun can you replace that SELECT with EXPLAIN SELECT and post the result?

Comment: vps, shared host, local host ... ci_sessions schema. lots of missing information in this question.

Comment: Edited with explain select :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put a multi-column index on `session_id` and `user_agent`. Then it should not take any real amount of time to perform the queries, even if you have millions of rows.

Comment: Thanks for that tip, `user_agent` wasn't actually an index. The speed is now good again, but I also submitted a ticket to the hosting provider and they said they "did something that should have fixed it". So I'll need to find out what exactly they did.

Comment: But to optimize for your above queries, it should not be separate indexes on the two, but one index on both columns, starting with `session_id`.

Comment: Maybe the host has allocated more memory to MySQL, this is good, but using correct indexes are what you should be focusing on.

Comment: Ah I understand, I've made it a multi column index now. Should it be a primary/unique index?